# Message Queue with C passing 2 numbers and 1 operator but getting error at server file

Tags: c, linux, message-queue, system-calls

In message queue I have created server.c and client.c. Created a structure with 2 numbers, 1 char  for operator and 1 is for message type.
The program is about to send the 2 numbers and an operator to the server and from server execute that and sent back the answer of that expression to the client.

But i am continuously getting following error

> Identifier Removed

I don't know where I am doing wrong.

**header.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

**client.c**

```
#include "./header.h"
#define KEY 777
#define SIZE 50

struct message
{
    long type;
    double no1, no2;
    char operator;
    char ans[SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    struct message msg;

    int qid = msgget((key_t)KEY, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (qid < 0)
        perror("Error creating queue");
    else
    {
        printf("Enter no1 : ");
        scanf("%lf", &msg.no1);
        printf("Enter no2 : ");
        scanf("%lf", &msg.no2);
        getc(stdin);
        printf("Enter operator : ");
        msg.operator= getchar();
        msg.type = 1;
        if (msgsnd(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.type), IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
            perror("Error to write data");
        else
        {
            // if (msgrcv(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg.ans), 2, 0) < 0)
            //     perror("error to read response");
            // else
            // {
            //     printf("%s\n", msg.ans);
            // }
        }
        msgctl(qid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`

**server.c**

```
#include "./header.h"
#define KEY 777
#define SIZE 50

struct message
{
    long type;
    double no1, no2;
    char operator;
    char ans[SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    struct message msg;

    int qid = msgget((key_t)KEY, IPC_CREAT | 0666);

    if (qid < 0 && errno != EEXIST)
        perror("Error creating queue");
    else
    {
        if (msgrcv(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg) - sizeof(msg.type), 1, 0) < 0)
            perror("Reading error");
        else
        {
            printf("%lf\n", msg.no1);
            int flag = 0;
            double ans = 0;
            switch (msg.operator)
            {
            case '+':
                ans = msg.no1 + msg.no2;
                break;
            case '-':
                ans = msg.no1 - msg.no2;
                break;
            case '/':
                ans = msg.no1 / msg.no2;
                break;
            case '*':
                ans = msg.no1 * msg.no2;
                break;
            default:
                flag = 1;
                snprintf(msg.ans, sizeof(msg.ans), "Invalid Operator");
                break;
            }
            printf("final decision\n");
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                snprintf(msg.ans, sizeof(msg.ans), "Total = %lf", ans);
            }
            printf("%s\n", msg.ans);
            // msg.type = 2;
            // if (msgsnd(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0)
            //     perror("Error to reply");
        }

        msgctl(qid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what exactly you do to get the error message. Copy&paste the full error message to the question. BTW: The file `header.h` which only includes system header files is strange style. It would be better to use a common header file for the structure definition and `#define`s that must be the same in client and server.

Comment: The problem is I am not getting the proper output and loosing the data inbetween. But after debugging the program I have found the mistake that I have called the msgctl method on both sides (server and client) and due to that, the message queue is getting deleted automatically if any of the sides completes its execution first. So the second side is not getting the data. As a solution, I have removed the msgctl from the server.c and only kept it to client.c and that works perfectly.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add requested information instead of writing a comment. The description "I am not getting the proper output" is not sufficient. You should write what input you use what output you expect and what you actually get and if necessary explain what's wrong with the actual output. Similar for "loosing the data inbetween". How exactly do you see that you are using data? What data do you expect based on your example input and what do you actually see? ... Even if you solved your problem it would be good to improve the question and write an answer yourself.